# Good agreement 'Alkali behaviour - Drude model'

Tags: solid-state-physics, electric-current

I am studying the Drude model for metals: it is assumed that atoms of a metallic element are brought together to form a metal, the valence electrons become detached and wander freely through the metal, while the ions remain immobile.

I am analysing all the results of this theory, for instance the 'Hall coefficient' or the 'plasma frequency' and I verify that the all the outcomes well conform to the experimental measures just for alkali metals. On the other hand the Drude model's relations describes quite well the behaviour of metals like Cu, Au, Ag but absolutely not the other metal's one.

I know this model is based on the kinetic theory, whose strongest assumption is that the molecules have to be treated like dimensionless particles. If I compare Be++ to Li+ I note that the radius of the first element is approximately the half of the second.

So, why can I appreciate a better agreement for alkali metals in spite of the others?